# Modify the display of one field by the value of another field

Tags: hooks

We have a content type with a date range element on our D8 site. I got a request to hide the display of the end date if the content editor decided so.

From testing, the content editor can't delete the end date-- the field fails validation if an end date has already been specified. And anyways, they don't want to delete the end date-- they want to maintain that information-- they only want it not to display to the public audience, in certain circumstances.

I started to approach this by adding a second field to the content type, a boolean checkbox "Hide End Date". I wrote a `hook_preprocess_field` in our .theme file in order to change the display of the date range value. But after debugging the variables, I realized that the date range field doesn't have any information about the value of the "hide end date" field, of course.

I'm not sure how best to proceed. Is `hook_preprocess_node` the place where I can look at both field values, and alter the value of the date range field? Will that affect display of the field throughout the site, including views?

Answer (score 1):

Add a boolean field as a condition to hide the end-date is a fine solution. For hiding the field you can either check for the boolean in the template:

```
{% if $node->field_hide_end_date->value %}
    {{ $node->field_range->value|format_date('my_custom_date_format') }}
{% else %}
    {# Original version of the field #}
    {{ $content['field_range'] }}
{% endif %}
```

Or change the value in a preprocess method

```
function custom_module_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if (array_key_exists('field_period', $variables['elements'])) {
    $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];

    if ($node->field_hide_end_date->value) {
      $variables['elements']['field_period'] = [
        '#markup' => (new DrupalDateTime($node->field_period->value))->format('d-m-Y'),
      ];
    }
    // else: business as usual.
  }
}
```